# Problems querying a user defined table with a Parameter in SapB1

Tags: sapb1

I am making a query for an API. I make the query in the query editor. I get there by clicking tools->queries->user queries-> select a query

In the editor I write the following:

```
select * from "@FR_RETAILADDR" where "U_FR_STORECODE" = [%code]
```

that does not work. I am given the following error:

```
"" (SWEI)
```

Any user defined table does not allow a parameter to be given. I can do the exact save with the OCRD table.

A side note my company just switched to SAP B1 last week. So we are all new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a trick by SAP B1. The query returns an error in SAP, but if you actually run the query through the API it works fine. So the solution is to try ignoring SAP if the error returned does not exist.

It is a bug in SAP B1

Answer (score 0):

The alias **T0** was missing.
So it will work:

select * from "@FR_RETAILADDR" **T0** where **T0**."U_FR_STORECODE" = [%code]

Comment: the alias is not that important.

Comment: The alias is important, so that SAP understands which table and which field belongs to which parameter. Please test you this Query with Alias and without Alias.